# UIViewController loads empty when loading programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

`UIViewController` loads empty `UIViews` with this code

```
let screen = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Detail")

myview.addSubview(screen.view)
```

it loads only UIView's parent view, but this `UIViewController` contains some subviews in Storyboard like `UIButton`, `UIImageView` and some labels but it doesn't load any of this just empty `UIView`. Maybe I made a mistake in my above code :(

Comment: I want to show the UIView as Overlay and i don't want segue bcs i want my previous view controller stay same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load sub views of your screen with this code, add this line right after `myview.addSubview(screen)`

```
screen.loadView()
```

This will load all sub views of the `screen`

Comment: its not `loadSubview` its `loadView` and its working.

Comment: Generally, `screen.loadViewIfNeeded()` is more secure as it loads the view only if it is not loaded yet.